# Google sheets: convert ragged array for to 2D array

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have multiple columns in a single row in a ragged array and want to convert this to a 2d array.

[image]

This example can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WOq0_IpPw5b0sQKJo3TYg_MSkpa4gfMsPo_v9Mingfc/edit#gid=0)

I realize that [similar questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91412/convert-jagged-array-to-2d-array-in-google-sheets) have been asked for multiple entries in a single cell; however, I cannot figure out how to handle having multiple output columns.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be done with a formula, but this does it with script:

```
function reOrder() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")//Data sheet
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")//new sheet
  var lr=s.getLastRow()
  var lc=s.getLastColumn()
  var row=s.getRange(2,1,lr-1,lc).getValues()//get data values
  var array=[]// array for new data
  for(var i=0;i<row.length;i++){
     for(var j=1;j<row[0].length;j=j+3){  
      if(row[i][j+1]==''){break}// If date is blank break row loop
         array.push([row[i][0],row[i][j]," ",row[i][j+1],row[i][j+2]])//new format
    }}
   s1.getRange(2,1,array.length,5).setValues(array)//write array to Sheet2
}
```

You haven't shared your spreadsheet. Here is a copy of what I tested with. I put the new data on a separate sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KDtzOWZiHra7QYsTrqt40WO4_A-N-LZnKup38jAwIYk/edit?usp=sharing